# how to use the ngrx store inside ngrx effect? i need data from store for making api call

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

i need to use my store inside effect but im getting error.
what is the correct way to do so?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your selected state is itself an Observable you can combine this into your stream with the `withLatestFrom` operator.

This is a rough example but I think you're looking for something along the lines of:

```js
@Effect()
loadEstateOwners$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(EstateOwnerListActionTypes.LoadEstateOwners),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select('userProfile')),
  map(([actions, user]) => {
    // Do something ...
  })
);
```

More info on `withLatestFrom` in the rxjs docs here:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom.html

Comment: now i have different error when im using the service inside the map   ERROR Error: Effect "EstateOwnersEffects.loadEstateOwners$" dispatched an invalid action: undefined   why is it happening?

Comment: your effects must map to an action of some description (unless you flag them as `dispatch: false`), are you returning one from inside the `map`?

Comment: this is my effect now, im dispatching an action     this is the effect now but im getting thhe error   https://jsfiddle.net/r4j60t15/

Comment: Also given you're making an API call you'll probably want to use merge/switch map as in the example here https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/effects#example

Comment: @AlexKoretzki you're not actually returning anything from the map in the jsfiddle you posted. ;-)

Comment: im dispaching an action, this worked for me before :)

Comment: Yeah but you have braces in the fat arrow function now, arrow functions with braces need a `return`. Try this or remove the braces/return statement https://jsfiddle.net/zo1t2dkx/

Comment: can you please edit my fiddle? im little bit lost :)